# How to load windows form on custom folder click using outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin

I have added a solution module having a custom folder in MS outlook 2010. I need to open a windows form on folder click event. The form should display in main central region of outlook window (I think it is called an inspector).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the Explorer.FolderSwitch event and display your form if the desired folder is current.

Comment: I can get the folder switch event but does not know how to open windows form in current outlook window in webviewpane region.

Comment: Take a look at this article: Outlook Folder Homepage: Hosting WPF, ActiveX and Windows Forms controls: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e2eblog/archive/2008/01/09/outlook-folder-homepage-hosting-wpf-activex-and-windows-forms-controls.aspx. This approach is actually much easier with add-ins designed using the Add-in Express framework.